# Parsing XML file and coverting it to array of objects

Tags: php, json, xml

I'm trying to get the XML contents and organize it as objects to retreive them in json file.

XML structure:

```
<lorem date="2017-01-01">
    <ipsum key="a">0001</ipsum>
    <ipsum key="b">0002</ipsum>
    <ipsum key="c">0003</ipsum>
    <ipsum key="d">0004</ipsum>
</lorem>
```

and PHP

```
<?php
    $URL = simplexml_load_file("http://www.example.com");
    foreach($URL -> lorem -> ipsum as $item){
        $arr = array($item["key"] => $item["value"]);
    }
    echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

At the end i would like to get json returned with the following structure:

```
{
"a": "0001",
"b": "0002",
"c": "0003",
"d": "0004",
}
```

But i'm stuck on how to retrieve values between the `ipsum` tags. And also the code above doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Do `(string)$item` instead of `$item["value"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code like this

```
<?php
    $URL = simplexml_load_file("http://www.example.com");
    foreach($URL->ipsum as $item){
        $arr[] = array((string)$item["key"] => (string)$item);
    }
    echo json_encode($arr);


    //for the format you show above
    $URL = simplexml_load_file("http://www.example.com");
    $arr = new stdClass();
    foreach($URL->ipsum as $item){
        $key = (string)$item["key"];
        $arr->{$key} = (string)$item;
    }
    echo json_encode([$arr]);
?>
```

- via `(string)$item["key"]` you access always a node attribute
- via `$item->subnode` you get the child node(s)
- via `(string)$item` you get the content of the current node

Comment: I'm getting an empty array.

Comment: Even better, wish i could upvote 5x :) Thanks a lot!